# Macro code for sorting by color in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a macro to organize my database by its highlight colors of white, blue, green, orange, and red (in that order). Each colored row is textually marked with the initial of its color. So I'm trying to create a macro that firstly organizes alphabetically by the color text row (making it 'B', 'G', 'O', 'R', 'blank'), and then bringing the blanks to the top through Google Sheet's new color sort tool.

However, Google Sheet's color sort tool doesn't seem to record accurately in macros. It writes code to reverse alphabetize (*sort(1, false)*), which is very unhelpful:

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A9').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().sort(1, true)
  .sort(1, false);
};
```

Any solution to this? Does anyone know the appropriate code? Can't seem to find help anywhere online, and feels like the code needs to exist if the tool does. Thanks in advance.